# C++ override understanding with different method's signatures

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual

I expects that in c++ you can override method if it has same signature in Base and Derived classes including name, arguments and return type.

If I try compile something like this I'll failure on both methods (get, get2) expectedly:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  A() {}
  virtual int get() { return 0; }
  virtual int *get2() { return 0; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  B() {}
  float get() override { return 0.f; }
  float *get2() override { return 0.f; }
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  cout << a.get() << endl;
  cout << b.get() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I have code:

```
#include <iostream>
class C
{
public:
  C(){};
  virtual int get() { return 0; };
};

class D : public C
{
public:
  D(){};
  int get() override { return 1; };
};

class E : public D
{
public:
  E(){};
  virtual int get() { return 2; };
};

class A
{
public:
  A() { d = new D(); }
  virtual D *get() { return dynamic_cast< D * >(d); }
  D *d;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  B() { d = new E(); }
  E *get() override { return dynamic_cast< E * >(d); }
};

class Z : public A
{
public:
  Z() { d = new E(); }
  C *get() override { return dynamic_cast< C * >(d); }
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  Z z;
  cout << a.get()->get() << endl;
  cout << b.get()->get() << endl;
  cout << z.get()->get() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

And I expect failure on both classes (B and Z). But I got failure only on class Z. Can someone explain this?

Comment: You may not change the return type from int to float for virtual functions.

Comment: please include the complete error message in the quesiton. I cannot reproduce what you report. When I try to compile I get errors not only for `Z` https://godbolt.org/z/favYdj

Comment: compilers have a flag that tells them to stop after the n-th error. You are not using this, are you?

Comment: You cannot usually change the return type of a overridden virtual function, _but_, if the abstract virtual method returns a pointer to a base class, you can return a pointer to a derived class.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, for your link i saw 2 errors for class Z, but no errors for class B, I expect 1 for B and 1 for Z. And I do not got 100+ errors on this example :) But thanks to prapin and chris-uzdavinis all become clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a base class declares a virtual function that returns a pointer or reference to a class, then overriding virtual functions *can* return a pointer or reference to a class type that derives from the base function's declared return type.
This is known as "covariant return type".

Example:

```
class Object {};
class Derived : public Object {};

class Interface {
public:
    virtual Object* get() = 0;
};

class Impl : public Interface {
public:
    Derived* get() override { return nullptr; } // OK
};
```

If you have a pointer to Interface and call get(), you get back an Object*, since Derived* is convertible to Object* due to inheritance.

However, if you have an instance of Impl, and you call `get()` directly on it, you can benefit from the more specific return type.  (After all, if you're working with the impl type rather than its interface, it's not a problem to know more about the implementation.)

According to the standard:

> [class.virtual] 11.6.2.8:
> The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to the return type of the overridden function or covariant with the classes of the functions. If a function D::f overrides a function B::f, the return types of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria:
>
> - both are pointers to classes, both are lvalue references to classes, or both are rvalue references to classes
> - the class in the return type of B::f is the same class as the class in the return type of D::f, or is an unambiguous and accessible direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of D::f
> - both pointers or references have the same cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of D::f has the same cv-qualification as or less cv-qualification than the class type in the return type of B::f.